# How to add last 10 character after truncating the string

Tags: bash, truncate

I'm trying to do it with multi lines

```
words="
What do you think about the kitten outside?
The tattered work gloves speak of the many hours of hard labor he endured throughout his life.
Hello
Hi
"
```

I used `cut -c -17` to truncate it.
I'm trying to output it like this:

```
What do you think...n outside?
The tattered work... his life.
Hello
Hi
```

Sorry i'm still noob in bash scripting... thanks

Comment: Easiest is to read from `words` one line at a time, `while read line; do ... done <<< $words` and then you can simply use the parameter expansion for indexing `"${line:0:17}"` for the first 17 and then `"${line: -10}"` for the last 10. (**note:** the space before `" -10"` is required, or enclose in parens `"(-10)"`) You will need to add a length check on `${#line}` and only output the last 10 (or less) if the length is greater than 17.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I forgot to mention, i used that looping too but it seems too slow when reading hundreds of lines of sentences

Comment: Well, if you find yourself attempting to store hundreds of lines as a single variable -- you need to store them in some other manner. If reading from a file use `readarray` (synonymous to `mapfile`) to read the file into an indexed array. Variables will store what you tell them, but (without looking at the bash source code), I suspect associating hundreds of lines of input as a single variable would likely incur additional overhead.

Comment: @NebDev Sounds like the solution you're looking for is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, you can read each line separately and figure out the suffix length (if less than 10) as follows

```sh
#!/bin/bash

words="
What do you think about the kitten outside?
The tattered work gloves speak of the many hours of hard labor he endured throughout his life.
Hello
Hi
"

while read line; do                           # loop reading each line
  len=${#line}                                # get line length
  [ "$len" -eq 0 ] && continue                # if zero len, get next line
  suffix=0                                    # set suffix length 0
  [ "$len" -gt 17 ] && suffix=$((len - 17))   # get max suffix length
  [ "$suffix" -ge 10 ] && suffix=10           # if > 10, set to 10
  printf "%s" "${line:0:17}"                  # output first 17 chars
  if [ "$suffix" -gt 0 ]; then                # if suffix > 0, output
    printf "...%s\n" "${line: -$suffix}"
  else                                        # otherwise output \n
    printf "\n"
  fi
    
done <<< $words        # feed loop with "herestring" from words
```

Note: `[ ... ] && do_something` is just shorthand for `if [ ... ]; then do_something; fi`. You can use the same shorthand with `||` as well. But, **avoid** chaining `[ ... ] && do_something || do_something_else` as the `||` will be executed if the first part fails for any reason. (so it isn't a shortcut for `if [...]; then ... else; fi`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./prefixsuffix.sh
What do you think...n outside?
The tattered work... his life.
Hello
Hi
```